# Does Twilio Chat has `onUserAddded` event on webhook?

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

I want to use `onUserAdded` for tracking metrics, but seems not to be firing even though it is listed on chat instance webhook settings. It does not exist though on docs which necessitated this question.

Comment: @philnash Any idea on this? Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know why it's not documented. Do you have the check box checked for the webhook in your chat instance settings? I'm investigating this internally too.